# How can I do padding in Form made Button on my Controller

Tags: symfony

I wanna make a small padding in my Button so i can divide the Send Button the form my Mensagem box.

Here is a pic for more details:

[image]

I already tried making a style for it didnt seem work.

If there is any other code i should provide, ill edit.

Here is the function that makes the Whole form

```
public function contactus(Request $request)
            {
                //Formulário para enviar dados com estilos do w3 css    
                $mensagem_default = ['message' => ''];//mensagem default a ser enviada
                //cria um form type
                $form = $this->createFormBuilder($mensagem_default)
                //Adiciona o campo nome
                ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                    'label'=> 'O seu Nome', 'attr'=>[ 'class' => 'form-control'], 'required' => false 
                ])
                //adiciona a empresa   
                ->add('enterprise', TextType::class, [
                    'label'=> 'A sua Empresa', 'attr'=>[ 'class' => 'form-control'], 'required' => false 
                ])

                //adiciona o telemovel  
                ->add('phone', TextType::class, [
                    'label'=> 'O seu Telemovel', 'attr'=>[ 'class' => 'form-control'], 'required' => false 
                ])

                //Adiciona o campo email
                ->add('email', TextareaType::class, [
                    'label'=> 'Email', 'attr'=>[ 'class' => 'form-control'], 'required' => false
                ])

                //adiciona o assunto  
                ->add('subject', TextType::class, [
                    'label'=> 'Assunto', 'attr'=>[ 'class' => 'form-control'], 'required' => false 
                ])

                //Adiciona o campo mensagem
                ->add('message', TextareaType::class, [
                    'label'=> 'Mensagem', 'attr'=>[ 'class' => 'form-control'], 'required' => false
                ])
                //Adiciona o campo botão enviar dados
                ->add('send', SubmitType::class, [
                     'attr'=>['class' => 'btn btn-primary']
                ])
                ->getForm();

                // Renderiza os arreio para a página principal e Renderiza o formulario para o body
                return $this -> render('contactus.html.twig', ['page'=> 'contactus', 'form'=> $form ->createView(),]);
                }
```

Comment: Note that Symfony Best Practices recommends to add buttons in templates: https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#form-button-configuration

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using bootstrap. If so, you can add a bootstrap utility class for padding `.p-1 .p-2 .p-3`. But, what I think you really want is a **margin** above the button, for that you can use `.mt-1`, I have had problems with the `.mt-` classes and usually end up using `.m-1` combined with `.ml-0` to keep the left margin at zero. See [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/) for reference.

```
->add('send', SubmitType::class, [
    'attr'=>['class' => 'btn btn-primary m-1 ml-0']
])
```

Alternatively, you should also be able to add an inline style declaration like so:

```
->add('send', SubmitType::class, [
    'attr'=>[
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
        'style' => 'margin-top:1em;',
    ]
])
```

You can also use customized form rendering in your template, see [How to Customize Form Rendering](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)